# Javascript setcookie()

Tags: javascript

The following line of code sets an event to happen only once per 24 hours, how do I make it occur every 12 or 6 hours? Thanks

```
setCookie(1, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Did you even try changing the `24` to something else ?

Comment: Btw, `setCookie` isn't a standard function in JS (or jQuery), in fact, your `jQuery` tag is redundant. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: Setting a cookie does not by itself control any sort of event.  Perhaps you should show us the code that actually reads the cookie and acts on it so we can see what it is doing.  Plus, in the interest of readable code, you should be using descriptive strings for the cookie parameter name, not a single digit that has no meaning on its own.

Comment: It's a popunder code, the cookie limits the amount of times it is shown, so in a way it does control it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript references time in milliseconds, and so therefore the equation `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is converting 24 hours into milliseconds 
 **(24 hours * 60 minutes in a hour * 60 minutes in a second * 1000 seconds in a millisecond)**.

Therefore, 12 hours would look like: 
`setCookie(1, 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

and 6 hours would look like: 
`setCookie(1, 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

and just for fun, 5 days would look like: 
`setCookie(1, 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`